# IBM WebSphere MQ JMS Jar Files

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, sap-pi

I am using SAP PI to connect with IBM MQseries (v 5.3).

Whenever there is a network problem or any outage on WebSphere MQs, the SAP interfaces error out with the message

> Completion Code 2, Reason 2161, MQJMS2002

To fix this, we are being asked to deploy new client files.

Can anyone help us find these jar files?

I have downloaded the v7 client from http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=171&uid=swg24019253&loc=en_US&cs=utf-8&lang=en, but it doesn't contain jar files. It has rte files.

Comment: I would add to strmqm's comment that grabbing the jar files is not a complete install.  When the MQC7 SupportPac is fully installed, you also get trace utilities, National Language support, GSKit, sample programs, man pages and more.  When you need to open a PMR, many of these diagnostic tools are helpful in resolving problems.  That's why IBM's official position is that a full install is required for support.

Comment: Also, check the [tag:websphere-mq] tag wiki for links to the latest version of clients, downloads, JAR files, and docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .jar files are in MQC7 (the WebSphere MQ V7.0 Clients supportpac), which is where your link goes. The install location varies with platform, but will be a java/lib directory under the main install path e.g. on Linux it would be /opt/mqm/java/lib

Answer (score 2):

For anyone locating this question and wanting an answer it is now (quite recently) possible to obtain the MQ JMS jar files for direct use rather than having to go through an install.

Read more about it here: [Obtaining the WebSphere MQ classes for JMS](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21683398)